# What networking tools do video games use to get real-time communication?

Tags: networking, game-engine, multiplayer

I'm interested in understanding the networking technology behind video games -- specifically I'm interested in large multiplayer games and how companies are able to simulate real-time connection in these games.

What technology is generally used? Is it just WebSockets or is it something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1):

So an up and coming technology being used to implement real-time communications in video games is [Web Real-time Communications (WebRTC)](https://www.callstats.io/blog/the-beginners-guide-to-understanding-webrtc-in-3-minutes). It's just beginning to be used in [the entertainment space](https://www.callstats.io/blog/2018/08/15/how-the-entertainment-space-is-becoming-an-incredible-force-with-rtc-real-time-communication-verticals-series) for video games, live streaming, and more.

[BlogGeek.Me](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-gaming/) goes into a few specific instances where WebRTC is valuable for gaming. Games like [Agar.io, Deip.io and others](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13264952) were built with WebRTC way back before 2016. Definitely something to look into when building a video game with peer-to-peer communication.

*As a note - if I had to guess, this question was most likely downvoted because it is too vague, could elicit spam and personal opinions, and lacked research by the poster beforehand. There are a lot of articles on the underlying technology behind video games available with a quick Google search, which is outside of the scope of questions/answers on StackOverflow.*